# Programmatically get the Range of a text spread over multiple elements

Tags: javascript, dom, selection, browser-api

I have a `code` element, and I know the text I'm looking for is inside it, for example:

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum <span class="bold">dolor</span> sit amet
</p>
```

Note the `span` that is used for styling specific words.

Now, assume I have a reference to the `p` element, and I want to programmatically mark the `ipsum dolor sit` part, how can achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) API with a [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) argument to programmatically select text in an element.

The `Range` start and end positions accept a *Child Node* number, or *Character* inside a [`Text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) node. In our case, we need to reach the `Text` nodes to direct to the text position inside them (in our example, it will start on the first `Text` node of `p`, in position `11`, and will end on the last `Text` in position `4`).

To find the right node and the text position inside it, use the next function:

```js
const findPositionInsideTree = (node, position) => {
  if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    return { node, position };
  }
  for (let child of node.childNodes) {
    if (position <= child.textContent.length) return findPositionInsideTree(child, position);
    position -= child.textContent.length;
  }
};
```

This recursive code loops over the child nodes and counts the expected position inside each node.

And now you only need to call this function for your text, create a `Range` and add it to the `Selection`:

```js
const textStart = element.textContent.indexOf('ipsum dolor sit');
const textEnd = textStart + 'ipsum dolor sit'.length;

const start = findPositionInsideTree(element, textStart);
const end = findPositionInsideTree(element, textEnd);

const range = new Range();
range.setStart(start.node, start.position);
range.setEnd(end.node, end.position);

window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
window.getSelection().addRange(range)
```